# How to make async call one by one with async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have two simple async functions:
First:

```
const first = async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(1)
    },2000);
}
```

Second:

```
const second = async () => {
    console.log(2);
}
```

I'm trying to hold second function until first is done. My code:

```
router.post('/', errorHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {

        await first();
        await second();

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
);
```

But the second function executing first. How do I have to use `await` to get what I want? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why dont you use Promises. Just do the initial post followed by 2 then blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is it has no way to know when your code is done. If you change the first function to something like the following it should work.

```
const first = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(1);
            resolve();
        },2000);
    });
}
```

Basically what this is doing is returning a promise that will resolve after your timeout is done. That way your `await` will wait until the `resolve` function gets called.

You could also do something like the following to convert setTimeout to a promise.

```
const timeout = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
    });
}

const first = async () => {
    await timeout(2000);
    console.log(1);
}
```

But the biggest problem is you are trying to combine callbacks and promises (`await`). So at some point you have to convert that callback (setTimeout) into a promise so you can `await` it.

Comment: Simplifies to `const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,  ms));`